# THREE.js: combining smaa and ssao postprocessing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to combine [SMAA](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing_smaa) and [SSAO](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing_ssao) in my `THREE.EffectComposer` like this:

```
this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.renderer);

// Setup depth pass
depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();
depthMaterial.depthPacking = THREE.RGBADepthPacking;
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;
var pars = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter };
depthRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, pars );
// Setup SSAO pass
ssaoPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
ssaoPass.renderToScreen = true;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ "tDepth" ].value = depthRenderTarget.texture;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = this.camera.near;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = this.camera.far;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'onlyAO' ].value = false;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'aoClamp' ].value = .3;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'lumInfluence' ].value = 1;

this.ssaoPass = ssaoPass;
this.depthRenderTarget = depthRenderTarget;


smaapass = new THREE.SMAAPass( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
smaapass.renderToScreen = true;
this.composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera));
this.composer.addPass(ssaoPass);
this.composer.addPass(smaapass);
```

but unfortunately only smaapass gets applied.
I also tried inverting the order of `composer.addPass` but without success.
Where I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.renderer);
this.composer.addPass(renderPass);

// Setup depth pass
depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();
depthMaterial.depthPacking = THREE.RGBADepthPacking;
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;
var pars = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat };
depthRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, 
window.innerHeight, pars );
// Setup SSAO pass
ssaoPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
ssaoPass.uniforms[ "tDepth" ].value = depthRenderTarget.texture;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = this.camera.near;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = this.camera.far;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'onlyAO' ].value = false;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'aoClamp' ].value = .3;
ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'lumInfluence' ].value = 1;
ssaoPass.renderToScreen = false; // lviggiani edit

smaapass = new THREE.SMAAPass( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
smaapass.renderToScreen = true;
this.composer.addPass(ssaoPass);
this.composer.addPass(smaapass);
```

I made the `renderpass` above everything and added the `renderpass` before setting the `ssao`. I also put the `rendertoscreen` at the bottom of the setup instead at the top. Also removed the `this.depthRenderTarger = depthRenderTarger;`, unless you have set it somewhere else you don't need that. I also added the RGB format to the `depthrendertarget`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seems to work... If for example I set `ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'onlyAO' ].value = true;` I should only see ambient occlusion but I still see the image with no ao. If I comment out `this.composer.addPass(smaapass);` then I see only ao but of course no antialiasing

Comment: ok, I got it working by setting `ssaoPass.renderToScreen = false;`

Comment: Glad you found your answer anyway ✌ and good luck on your project ;)

Comment: Well I used your code and just turned `ssaoPass.renderToScreen = false;`, so the all credit goes to you! Thanks! (I have also edited your answer)

Comment: Thanks! And lets just say we solved it together then! I love taking these challenges and this community is great.